# Expectation Integral Identity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

it's known that for any random variable X:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X>y) dy - \int_{-\infty}^{0} P(X<y) dy $$

I'm trying to prove this doing the following:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_X(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} dy f_X(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x}  f_X(x) dydx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x}^{\infty}  f_X(x) dxdy = \\ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(X \geq x)dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X \geq x)dy + \int_{-\infty}^{0} P(X \geq x)dy $$

what am I missing?

Comment: Well for one thing $x \neq \int_0^y \ dy$. Do you mean to have $\int_0^x  \ dy$?

Comment: Second of all, you've done your change of variables incorrectly. How can $y$ go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ if $y \geq 0$?

Comment: Something like this holds for positive random variables.

Comment: And finally, you need to split up the case $x \geq 0$ and $x<0$ in order to properly do the change of variables. The bounds will be slightly different in those two cases.

Comment: Make use of $X=X^+-X^-$ (and consequently $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EX^+-\mathbb EX^-$) where $X^+=\max(X,0)$ and $X^-=\max(0,-X)$ are nonnegative random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion/correction of kccu:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_X(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x f_X(x) dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0} x f_X(x) dx = \\ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} f_X(x) dydx - \int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{x}^{0} f_X(x) dydx  = 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{\infty} f_X(x) dxdy - \int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_X(x) dxdy = \\
\int_{0}^{\infty} P(X>x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^{0} P(X<x) dx 
$$